# jQuery Validation rule based on select value

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, html-select

I have the following form.

```
<form id="myform">
    <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
        <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="zip_code" id="zip-code">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want the `zip_code` field to contain the `digits: true` rule when the selected country is `United States`. This is what I have tried based on [this code.](https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/#example-5)

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules:{
        zip_code: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 10,
            digits: function(element){
                return $("#country").val() == 'US';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: I was mistaken, this does enable `digits` validation, but when I change countries, the `digits` rule doesn't become false

Comment: except us other countries allow number only wright

Comment: @whoami US should be digits only. The other countries can have both letters and numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i notice few thing which you have done wrong, you have given variable instead of id,

```
   $("#myform").validate({
          rules:{
              zip_code: {
                  required: true,
                  maxlength: function() {
                    if($("#country").val() == 'US'){
                      return 5;
                    }else {
                      return 10;
                    }
                  },
                  digits: {
                  depends: function(element) {
                      return $("#country").val() == 'US';
                    }
                  }
              }
          }
      });
```

Comment: The variable was just a typo. However your answer seems to be working. I will mark it as accepted. I know this wasn't part of the original question but do you know how I could make it so the `maxlength` is `5` when the country is `US`, and `10` when it's any other country?

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski, i updated the answer, check it out.